# Where do I re-enable a build question in Visual Studio 2008 after clicking "do not ask again"?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

While building a program, I made a mistake and chose "do not ask again" to the question "this project is out of date, do you want to build it?"

How can I re-enable that question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run

If it's the one I think you mean. :)